# Why isn't em doubling the defined font size?

Tags: css

I understood that 2em doubled the size of the font that the element was calculated to have. But in this case, it doesn't seem to be working like that.

(On Chrome)

**Styles**

```
  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    .go-big {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  </style>
```

**HTML**

```
  <p>This should be 24 px</px>
  <p class="go-big">This should be 48 px?</px>
```

I have a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-em-question-deborahk

Since the `<p>` element style is set to 24px, I would assume that adding a class with a `font-size` of `2em` would double the font size to 48px. But it instead seems to double the default font size of 16 to 32px.

Is this a bug? Or something in the way these styles are inherited?

Comment: If I recall `em` is relative to the parent `font-size`. So whatever is wrapped around those paragraphs is the `font-size` you need to be concerned with. 32px makes sense since the default `font-size` for the `<body>` is 16px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`em` means my parent's font-size (when it comes to typographical properties like `fontSize`), according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths).

> Font size of the parent, in the case of typographical properties like font-size, and font size of the element itself, in the case of other properties like width.

`go-big` is a direct child of the `body` element so it `font-size:2em` indicates (2 * font-size of body).

You can test this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-em-question-deborahk-d3fqof?file=index.html), where I have changed body font-size to 24px and now it correctly shows 48px (for 2em).

Comment: Got it. Thanks! From the MDN documentation it just said "relative to the font size of the element": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Values_and_Units

Comment: Interesting that the two sets of documentation are so different. Your reference was much more clear than the one I was reading.

Comment: There is a clarification in the text I have linked though. It says for typographical elements (like properties) it has to do with the parent's font size , and for properties like `width` it has to do with the element itself.

Comment: Although the documentation linked by you still makes it a little unclear and I guess that could have been phrased better with more info actually